# How to use embedding_lookup with a batch of different length sequences in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Say I have an embedding tensor:

```
emb = [[1,1],
       [2,2],
       [3,3],
       [4,4]]
emb = tf.constant(emb)
```

I have a list of sequences:

```
inputs = [[0,1,2,3]
          [3,2]]
```

I'd like to lookup the `emb` and pad zeros to make each sequence has the same length:

```
  [[[1, 1],
    [2, 2],
    [3, 3],
    [4, 4]],

   [[4, 4],
    [3, 3],
    [0, 0],
    [0, 0]]]
```

I tried `tf.nn.embedding_lookup`, but got an error:

> ValueError: Argument must be a dense tensor: [[0, 1, 2, 3], [3, 2]] -
>   got shape [2], but wanted [2, 4].

Is it possible to achieve this without prepending `[0, 0]` to `emb`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`tf.nn.embedding_lookup(params, ids)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/nn.html#embedding_lookup) function only accepts dense, rectangular tensors as the `ids` argument. (In general, the same goes for all TensorFlow operators that expect a [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor) or tensor-like argument such as a NumPy array.)

For sparse data, you can use [`tf.nn.embedding_lookup_sparse()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/nn.html#embedding_lookup_sparse), which accepts a [`tf.SparseTensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor) as its argument, which can represent sequences of different lengths. A `tf.SparseTensor` is defined from three separate (dense) tensors, representing the indices of the non-zeroes, the values of the non-zeroes, and the overall dense shape. For  your example of inputs, the representation would be:

```
inputs_sparse = tf.SparseTensor(
    # The coordinates of the non-zero entries.
    indices=tf.constant([[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3],
                         [1, 0], [1, 1]]),
    # The values of the respective non-zero entries.
    values=tf.constant([0, 1, 2, 3,
                        3, 2]),
    # The shape of the corresponding dense tensor (must be >= [2, 4]).
    shape=[2, 4],
)
```

Comment: Hi mrry, I got `[[2.5, 2.5], [3.5, 3.5]]`. Is it possible not to calculate the mean and get the result in my post? Thanks.

Comment: See documention for tf.nn.embedding_lookup_sparse() since it provides a way to directly compute the mean.